# Constraints- My circle is not following the selected path in my follow path constraint

Tags: modifiers, constraints, path

I am trying to make the circle follow the brazier curve path with a follow path constraint but it is only the blue line that is following it.

What am I doing wrong?  Saw lots of tutorials but still, my circle is not following the path.

[image]
Thanks, for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your Forward axis (to 'X') it should work.  Have your Forward and Up axis be perpendicular, never the same.   X/Z, Z/X, etc...

Example: [image]

[image]